# moment.js invalid date in safari and FF

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have the following date:
06-24-2016 02:18:13 PM

I'm trying to use moment.js but getting invalid date in Safari and FF using the following:

```
moment(data.d.results[0].Updated_On).format('MMMM Do YYYY'))
```

Not sure what I need to do to get it working an all browsers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

just provide the correct format for your date, then it will work everywhere

```
var d = "06-24-2016 02:18:13 PM";
alert(moment(d, "MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss A").format("MMMM Do YYYY"))
```

Answer (score 0):

probably not the recommended way.. but this works for me in all browsers:

```
moment(data.d.results[0].Updated_On, "MM-Do-YYYY").format('MMMM Do YYYY'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not applicable to most. But in my case I was appending 'z' to my date string. Which worked fine in Chrome but failed testing in Safari. Simply change the 'z' to a capitalized 'Z' fixed for me.

Thought I'd share this rare edge case.